# Continuity of map from Lipschitz functions to rough paths

Tags: lipschitz-functions, rough-path-theory

- Suppose that $X_t$ is an $\mathbb{R}^d$-valued geometric $p$-rough path, satisfying
  $$
  \Vert \mathbf{X}^j_{s,t} \Vert \leq M(t-s)^{\frac{j}{p}},
  $$
  for some $M>0$ and every $j \in \{1,\dots,p\}$,
- Let $Lip(p)$ be the set of Lipschitz functions from $\mathbb{R}^d$ to itself which are $p$-times differentiable and whose $p^{th}$ derivative is Lipschitz.  We make this into a *complete metric space* using the an analogue of the metric found in [this paper](http://yadda.icm.edu.pl/yadda/element/bwmeta1.element.bwnjournal-article-doi-10_7151_dmdico_1170/c/dmdico.1170.pdf), that is 
  $$
  d(f,g)\triangleq \max\left\{
  Lip(f-g),\sup_{x \in \mathbb{R}^d}\|f(x)-g(x)\|_{\mathbb{R}^d}
  \right\}
  .
  $$

Is the function $F:Lip(p)\rightarrow \mathcal{G}^{(p)}(\mathbb{R}^d)$ by
$$
f\mapsto \int_0^{\cdot} f(X)dX,
$$
continuous?  I expect that it is infact Lipschitz but I'm a bit new to the field.

Comment: Please clarify: What is the topology on $\mathcal{G}^{(p)}(\mathbb{R}^d)$? Is $\int f(X)\,d X$ a rough integral (i.e. integral wrt $\mathbf{X} = (X,\mathbb{X})$) or just integral wrt the path $X$? If $X$ is differentiable why would you need to consider the rough path $\mathbf{X}$? And what is $Lip(f-g)$?

Comment: Hello, yes it is a rough integral.  Also I never claimed $X$ was differatiable.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. Please clarify the notations $Lip(f-g)$ and $\mathcal{G}^{(p)}(\mathbb{R}^d)$ (and the topology on it). In the mean time, check out the Young-type inequality for rough integrals in p. 53 (theorem 4.10) of [this](http://www.hairer.org/notes/RoughPaths.pdf) book. You can probably use it yourself to prove the continuity assertion.

Answer (score 0):

Yes in fact the beauty of rough integrals is continuity in the 1-form $dX$ as well, see theorem 10.41 in ["Multidimensional Stochastic Processes as
Rough Paths: Theory and Applications"](https://page.math.tu-berlin.de/%7Efriz/master4_May6th.pdf)

[image]

Here the $V^1,V^2$ are two different choices of $f$.